# Convert value based on index location in Python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I need the value from the first column, first row index (iloc[0]) in df1, and to convert the matching value in df2 to 0.

I was trying something like this but I'm aware the syntax is out

```
df2[df1['ID'].iloc[0]] = 0
```

df1:

```
ID   Name X
6539 CM   20
9999 FM   30
```

df2:

```
Out 1  Out 2  Out 3  Out 4  Out 5
7000   8000   6539   6539   6539
```

So the output would be

```
Out 1  Out 2  Out 3  Out 4  Out 5
7000   8000   0      0      0
```

Comment: `df2.replace(df.iloc[0,0], 0)`?

Comment: ``df1[str(df1.index[0])] = 0``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df2.replace(df.iloc[0,0], 0)
```

Full example:

import pandas as pd

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2],
    'b': [3,4]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,1],
    'b': [1,1]
})

df2.replace(df.iloc[0,0],0)
```

Returns:

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  0
```

---

#### Timings:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1]*10000)
df2 = pd.concat([df2]*10000)

%timeit df2.replace(df.iloc[0,0],0, inplace=True)
%timeit df2[df2 == df1.iloc[0, 0]] = 0
```

Returns:

```
341 µs ± 9.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.24 ms ± 39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: @jezrael are you sure?

Comment: Going out for lunch. Heheh

Comment: Hehe ok. I haven’t looked under the hood but I thought it might be quick.

Answer (score 2):

I think need change values by boolean mask:

```
df = df2.mask(df2 == df1.iloc[0,0], 0)
```

Or:

```
df2[df2 == df1.iloc[0, 0]] = 0
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df2 == df1.iloc[0,0], 0, df2),index=df2.index,columns=df2.columns)
```

---

```
print (df)
   Out 1  Out 2  Out 3  Out 4  Out 5
0   7000   8000      0      0      0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df2 == df1.iloc[0,0])
   Out 1  Out 2  Out 3  Out 4  Out 5
0  False  False   True   True   True
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(100)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2],
    'b': [3,4]
})


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000,1000)))


In [106]: %timeit df2.replace(df1.iloc[0,0],0, inplace=True)
2.99 ms ± 324 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [107]: %timeit df2.mask(df2 == df1.iloc[0,0], 0)
22.8 ms ± 1.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [108]: %timeit df2[df2 == df1.iloc[0, 0]] = 0
19.6 ms ± 497 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [109]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df2 == df1.iloc[0,0], 0, df2),index=df2.index,columns=df2.columns)
5.81 ms ± 91.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

If there is a few columns and many rows:

```
np.random.seed(100)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2],
    'b': [3,4]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(1000,10)))

In [116]: %timeit df2.replace(df1.iloc[0,0],0, inplace=True)
856 µs ± 12.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [117]: %timeit df2.mask(df2 == df1.iloc[0,0], 0)
1.23 ms ± 25.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [118]: %timeit df2[df2 == df1.iloc[0, 0]] = 0
1.21 ms ± 4.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [119]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df2 == df1.iloc[0,0], 0, df2),index=df2.index,columns=df2.columns)
445 µs ± 13.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```